# Best way to orchestrate a sequence of events based on user input in a browser game?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, game-development, nuxtjs3

I really struggled to phrase the title, which shows how lost I am. I consider myself a good web developer, but structures like this break my head :D

–––

### The game

I'm remaking a little ear-training game of mine (http://twelvenotes.co/) with Nuxt3.

The game features 8 rounds of questions. Each round plays 2 musical notes and the player must tell which one is higher.

The interactive concept for the new version has changed. The game does not start automatically, but waits for a "Start now" input from the Playeyr. Each round the two notes play automatically in sequence. The Player has two options now:

1. Click on one note to lock in the answer to which note he thinks is higher
2. Replay the two notes in the same sequence, but lose "1 life" (or "extra listen") of 3

Answering a question shows an animation indicating if Player is right or wrong. After the animation is completed the game should move to the next round automatically and also start the round automatically, after the animated transition to the new round is done.

The whole game and each round individually is timed with a visible stop watch which will influence the final score.

After 8 rounds the Player is presented with an end screen showing the performance and a score.

### The problem

As of right now, Creating the array of playable rounds, locking in the answer, moving to the next round, playing notes, replaying notes are all separate functions.

Now to the question: Whats the best way to control all these functions? Especially with timeouts needed for animations and playing notes etc. it's hard to structure which function does what and who tells it when to do it.

Who controls when we move to the next round and when we will start that round? Moving to the next round should only be possible when the current round has been answered. But should all of this be the job of `moveToNextRound()`? And who actually starts the round as in playing the notes, starting a stopwatch for this round etc. – And who stops the timer of the played round when the round has been answered? Is that a job for `moveToNextRound()` or `startRound(roundIndex)` or is that the job of a new function `finishRound()` - but who then calls `finishRound()`? Or should it be `finishCurrentRound()`. When a question is answered we need time for an animation telling the player if his answer was right or not and so on and so forth...

... I guess you get the picture. Structuring this is not easy for me. While doing it I constantly go back and forth between which function does what.

### The question

Can you guys point me to best practices or resources in that field? Only thing I can think of googling is: "Gamecontroller"... which obviously only gives you results for gaming console gamepads.

Thanks!